# Blocking names in Likes on photos

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-photos

Is there a way to block your friends from seeing who liked your photos on Facebook, but still see the number of likes? I mean "1000 people like X's photo" but not showing who.

Answer (score 2):

No, as of now there is no way to block names in Likes on photos. Facebook has not provided any algorithm for this.

Comment: Dear downvoter, may I know why downvote?